# msvc /permissive- std::string overloaded operator '=' is ambiguous

Tags: c++, visual-c++, implicit-conversion, move-constructor, move-assignment-operator

It compiles with `/permissive` but fails with `/permissive-`. What is not conforming and how to fix it?

Why it's fine in `(2)` but fails in <strike>`(4)`</strike>`(3)`?
If I remove `operator long` it also fine.

How to fix it without changing call site `(3,4)`?

```
#include <string>
struct my
{
    std::string myVal;
    my(std::string val): myVal(val) {}

    operator std::string() { return myVal; };
    operator long() { return std::stol(myVal); };
};
int main()
{
    struct MyStruct
    {
        long n = my("1223"); // (1)
        std::string s = my("ascas"); // (2)
    } str;
    str.s = my("ascas"); // (3)
    str.n = my("1223"); // (4)
}
```

error message

```
error C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous
xstring(2667): note: could be 'std::basic_string<...> &std::basic_string<...>::operator =(const _Elem)'
        with
        [
            _Elem=char
        ]
xstring(2648): note: or 'std::basic_string<...> &std::basic_string<...>::operator =(const std::basic_string<...> &)'
xstring(2453): note: or 'std::basic_string<...> &std::basic_string<...>::operator =(std::basic_string<...> &&) noexcept(<expr>)'
Source1.cpp(17): note: while trying to match the argument list '(std::string, my)'
```

Comment: comparing 2 with 4 is this a typo? wouldnt it make more sense to compare 1 with 4 (or 2 with 3) ?

Comment: On possible way to fix it is:  `str.s = my("ascas").operator std::string();`  (although I don't often see that kind of approach in the wild.)

Comment: @Eljay Why not `str.s = std::string(my("ascas"));`?

Comment: [Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/mZqQT5). MSVC compilation ends with success.

Comment: @MarekR You didn't use `/permissive-`.

Comment: @cpplearner [fixed](https://godbolt.org/z/I0TjLv).

Comment: @uneven_mark • or `str.s = my("ascas").myVal;`

Comment: This is why making conversion operators explicit is generally a good thing.

Comment: @rubenvb  but I want it to be implicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vlad from Moscow answer have a nice explanation. But there was no solution.
Here it is using SFINAE

```
template<typename T = long, typename = std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_same_v<T, long> || std::is_same_v<T, int>>>
operator T() const
{
    return l();
}

operator std::string() const
{
    return s();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

<sup>I suppose you meant *it's fine in (2) but fails in (3)*</sup>

Note that the #2 is initialization, which calls the [constructor of `std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string); the #3 is assignment, which calls the [assignment operator of `std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D). They're different things.

The invocation of assigment operator is ambiguous because the assignment operator of `std::string` has an overload taking `char`, which could be implicitly converted from `long` (which is a stardard conversion), then leads to ambiguity (with the assignment operators taking `std::string`, as the compiler complained). Both the [implicit conversion sequence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) contain one user-defined conversion (from `my` to `std::string` or `long`), they have the same rank in [onverload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution).

The invocation of constructor is fine because it doesn't have such overload (taking `char`).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that in the case #2 there is used a constructor while in the case #3 there is used an assignment operator.

The assignment operator is overloaded like

```
basic_string& operator=(charT c);
```

But there is no constructor that accepts only one argument of the type `charT`

So for the case #2 there is used the user-defined conversion operator

```
operator std::string() { return myVal; };
```

and then the constructor

```
basic_string(basic_string&& str) noexcept;
```

In the case #3 there are two posiibilities.

The first one is to call the conversion operator

```
operator std::string() { return myVal; };
```

and then the assignment operator

```
basic_string& operator=(basic_string&& str)
```

And the second one is to call the conversion operator

```
operator long() { return std::stol(myVal); };
```

and then the assignment operator

```
basic_string& operator=(charT c);
```

It is interesting to note the following additional case.

If you will wrote

```
str.s = { my("ascas") };
```

then there will not be an ambiguity. The compiler will select the operator that accepts an std::initializer_list. That is it will select the assignment operator

```
basic_string& operator=(initializer_list<charT>);
```

In this case there will be used the conversion operator

```
operator long() { return std::stol(myVal); };
```

but as the string `"ascas"` can not be converted to the type long a runtime error will occur

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  stol
```

Comment: How `permissive` resolves it? How to fix it without changing call site (3,4)?

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic Unfortunately I do not deal with MS VS.